# Can not start Marathon tests in Cygwin under Win 7

Tags: java, python, cmd, cygwin

Good day, I'm trying to start Marathon tests (http://marathontesting.com/) from Cygwin in Windows 7, and get same error each time:

Error: Could not find or load main class net.sourceforge.marathon.Main

From Windows CMD tests are working with no problem using this command:

```
marathon -batch C:\Users\asus\Desktop\my_tests\
```

But from Cygwin they don't work using command:

```
marathon -batch /cygdrive/c/Users/asus/Desktop/my_tests/
```

I'm tryed lot of things like this: `java -cp "cygpath path_to_marathon.jar"`   and such like, but no success.

Additional info:
Tests are writen on Jython and contained in the folder '..\my_tests\test.py
All patches to marathon, java, microemulator (using in the tests), jython, python and etc. are added to classpath/patch in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`cmd.exe /c 'marathon.bat -batch C:\Users\asus\Desktop\my_tests\'`.

The parameter is the project directory that is sent to Marathon's main as an argument. So it should be a valid Java File path.

Surprisingly, using `cmd` instead of `cmd.exe` does not work.